# Joining to OverlayItems

Tags: android, android-mapview, mapactivity

In a class derived from the `MapActivity` class, I want to join two `OverlayItems` with a line. So far, I have tried to override the `MapView`'s `onDraw` method but it is not possible because this method is declared `final`.

How can I do?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Comment: please update your code overhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `draw()` in your `Overlay` and draw what you wish.